# How to change the visibility timeout of an SQS message received using JMS Listener?

Tags: jms, amazon-sqs

Since there is no getReceiptHandle method on the message, how to change the visibility timeout of an SQS message received using [JMS Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-jms-code-examples.html)?

Comment: You probably need to cast the message to the SQS implementation class and use a non-JMS method.

Comment: I was not able to figure out how to cast it either, do you have any references for this approach? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation object for the `javax.jms.Message` you're receiving? If so, what is it?

Comment: It's https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/jms/Message.html

Comment: `javax.jms.Message` is an **interface**. You need to look at the object which is _implementing_ that interface. It will be a class from your SQS client.